# How can I get the most frequent 100 numbers out of 4,000,000,000 numbers?

Tags: java, algorithm

Yesterday in a coding interview I was asked how to get the most frequent 100 numbers out of 4,000,000,000 integers (may contain duplicates), for example:

```
813972066
908187460
365175040
120428932
908187460
504108776
```

The first approach that came to my mind was using HashMap:

```
static void printMostFrequent100Numbers() throws FileNotFoundException {
    
    // Group unique numbers, key=number, value=frequency
    Map<String, Integer> unsorted = new HashMap<>();
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"))) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String number = scanner.nextLine();
            unsorted.put(number, unsorted.getOrDefault(number, 0) + 1);
        }
    }

    // Sort by frequency in descending order
    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sorted = new LinkedList<>(unsorted.entrySet());
    sorted.sort((o1, o2) -> o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue()));

    // Print first 100 numbers
    int count = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sorted) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        if (++count == 100) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

But it probably would throw an OutOfMemory exception for the data set of 4,000,000,000 numbers. Moreover, since 4,000,000,000 exceeds the maximum length of a Java array, let's say numbers are in a text file and they are not sorted. I assume multithreading or Map Reduce would be more appropriate for big data set?

How can the top 100 values be calculated when the data does not fit into the available memory?

Comment: It depends on the source of those 4 billion numbers, and how many distinct values are expected. There is no single answer to this. --- E.g. if they are in a text file, map reduce is a good choice, but if the number of distinct values is relatively low, a `HashMap` is a good choice too. If they are in an RDBMS database, then use the database engine, i.e. `SELECT` statement with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Are the numbers sorted?

Comment: *What would be the best solution for this problem?* There is no universal "best" solution in real life. It is always about making trade offs. If memory isnt a hard requirement, your solution might be just fine. If fast but inaccurate solutions are possible, you might even train a UI and do guessing for you (some people now do that for sorting). Thus: voted to close as "opinion" question.

Comment: Is it known how many distinct values are there? Do all the values fit into 32 bits?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen
What would be your approach if numbers were sorted?

Comment: @阿尔曼 Just read the numbers from an end, and count the number of each unique instance.   You only need  to keep track of the 400 number occuring most so you can discard any number which has more than 400 other numbers that occur more.

Comment: The point of this problem is that you figure out the right questions to ask, not to show you can actually implement it

Comment: @sjoerd Please read all the comments. I was asked how to do it if the numbers were sorted.

Comment: @Sjoerd You can only edit comments for a short time after entering them, otherwise I would have.  But instead it turned out to be a teaching moment 

Comment: i would just drop all the numbers in a SQLite database with a counter, the SQLite db won't go out of ram until you go out of diskspace ^^

Comment: (`may contain duplicates` else the solution is any selection of 100 numbers, as each occurs once.)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If the data is **sorted**, you can collect the top 100 in `O(n)` where `n` is the data's size. Because the data is sorted, the distinct values are contiguous. Counting them while traversing the data once gives you the **global** frequency, which is not available to you when the data is not sorted.

See the sample code below on how this can be done. There is also an implementation (in Kotlin) of the entire approach on [GitHub](https://github.com/sorokod/Top100/)

**Note:** Sorting is not required. What **is** required is that distinct values are contiguous and so there is no need for ordering to be defined - we get this from sorting but perhaps there is a way of doing this more efficiently.

You can sort the data file using (external) merge sort in roughly `O(n log n)` by splitting the input data file into smaller files that fit into your memory, sorting and writing them out into sorted files then merging them.

---

---

About this code sample:

- Sorted data is represented by a `long[]`. Because the logic reads values one by one, it's an OK approximation of reading the data from a sorted file.
- The OP didn't specify how multiple values with equal frequency should be treated; consequently, the code doesn't do anything beyond ensuring that the result is top N values in no particular order and not implying that there aren't other values with the same frequency.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

class TopN {
    private final int maxSize;
    private Map<Long, Long> countMap;

    public TopN(int maxSize) {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        this.countMap = new HashMap(maxSize);
    }

    private void addOrReplace(long value, long count) {
        if (countMap.size() < maxSize) {
            countMap.put(value, count);
        } else {
            Optional<Entry<Long, Long>> opt = countMap.entrySet().stream().min(Entry.comparingByValue());
            Entry<Long, Long> minEntry = opt.get();
            if (minEntry.getValue() < count) {
                countMap.remove(minEntry.getKey());
                countMap.put(value, count);
            }
        }
    }

    public Set<Long> get() {
        return countMap.keySet();
    }

    public void process(long[] data) {
        long value = data[0];
        long count = 0;

        for (long current : data) {
            if (current == value) {
                ++count;
            } else {
                addOrReplace(value, count);
                value = current;
                count = 1;
            }
        }
        addOrReplace(value, count);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long[] data = {0, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7};
        TopN topMap = new TopN(2);

        topMap.process(data);
        System.out.println(topMap.get()); // [5, 6]
    }
}
```

Comment: No. There is too much data to find the top 100 in one pass, sorted or not. Consider there is 1 of every number except 100 which have 2 each. You would have to store the totals for every number right to the end, and that can’t be done in memory.

Comment: You just keep the top 100 numbers as you traverse the sorted data, if you already have 100 numbers, you knock out the number with the lowest count by a number with a higher count. In your example [0,1,2,....... 100, 100] by the time you get to 100 you have a set which looks like: {0 - 1, 1 - 1,  2 -1, ..., 99 - 1} now you have {100 - 2 } so you knock out some number with count 1 and  add {100 - 2}

Comment: you’re missing the point entirely. If the top scores are all the same, you have to keep all numbers. Again, consider the numbers appear exactly once, except the last 100 are duplicates of the largest 100 numbers. Even sorting doesn’t help.

Comment: I guess the question is what do you do if e.g. 101 numbers are all the most common - report 101 numbers or 100?

Comment: What to do when multiple values have the same frequency is actually not defined in the original post. The most extreme case is when all 4 billion values are distinct. My take is that that in this case, it makes no difference which of those 4 billion values are displayed as top 100.

Comment: @ilkkachu but the answer assumes that the numbers are sorted. Now, clearly that's not a particularly good assumption here (the example given by OP contradicts it), but with that assumption, you're guaranteed that the *next line up* won't repeat any of the smaller 99 numbers in your group of 100 distinct ones.

Comment: @David The most extreme edge case is 3999999900 distinct values, followed by 100 distinct values that have already appeared. The result is the last 100 values, because they appeared twice each, whereas all other values appeared once. There are no ties to break - the top 100 are clear winners. However, they were not determinable until the entire input had been processed, which means you need to keep track of the quantity of occurrences of 3999999900 values, and what those values are. This is not about breaking ties. Sorting or splitting then merging doesn’t help either (but both might!)

Comment: @Bohemian If the input is sorted, each of the 100 values that appear twice, will appear _twice in a row_.  That makes a huge difference.

Comment: @zwol sorting alone makes no difference if the highest values are the winners: a one-pass algorithm won’t work.

Comment: @Bohemian instead of top 100 lets do top 2. Can you produce a small data array that demonstrates your point, run it through my sample code and share here?

Comment: @Sjoerd it can’t be done in one pass. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64881720/256196)

Comment: @Bohemian It can be done in one pass - sorted or not, duplicate answers or not -  if the max integer read has a certain maximum size. See my answer.

Comment: @zwol (and others) are correct, and I was not, that after sorting only 1 pass is  required if there are no ties to break outside the winners - just keep track of the top 100 values and their frequencies found so far, displacing the bottom frequency if a better winner is encountered

Comment: @Bohemian You also need to keep track of the *current integer's count*, which is the bit that might have confused you.

Answer (score 23):

Integers are signed 32 bits, so if only positive integers happen, we look at 2^31 max different entries. An array of 2^31 bytes should stay under max array size.

But that can't hold frequencies higher than 255, you would say? Yes, you're right.

So we add an hashmap for all entries that exceed the max value possible in your array (255 - if it's signed just start counting at -128). There are at most 16 million entries in this hash map (4 billion divided by 255), which should be possible.

---

We have two data structures:

- a large array, indexed by the number read (0..2^31) of bytes.
- a hashmap of (number read, frequency)

Algorithm:

```
 while reading next number 'x'
 {
   if (hashmap.contains(x))
   {
     hashmap[x]++;
   }
   else
   {
     bigarray[x]++;
     if (bigarray[x] > 250)
     {
       hashmap[x] = bigarray[x];
     }
   }
 }

 // when done:
 // Look up top-100 in hashmap
 // if not 100 yet, add more from bigarray, skipping those already taken from the hashmap
```

I'm not fluent in Java, so can't give a better code example.

---

Note that this algorithm is single-pass, works on unsorted input, and doesn't use external pre-processing steps.

All it does is assuming a maximum to the number read. It should work if the input are non-negative Integers, which have a maximum of 2^31. The sample input satisfies that constraint.

---

The algorithm above should satisfy most interviewers that ask this question. Whether you can code in Java should be established by a different question. This question is about designing data structures and efficient algorithms.

Comment: I don't see anything in the question guaranteeing that the numbers all fit in 32-bit `int` as signed positive, i.e. 31-bit.  Comments on other answers have suggested corner cases like 3999999900 distinct values, which would have to include many negative numbers, or a larger type.  They're in ASCII decimal string format in the file, which imposes no limit at all on their size.  Good algorithm if you *can* make this assumption, though.

Comment: If you can assume 32-bit, you might use 4-bit buckets, two per uint8_t or whatever Java calls it.  That makes incrementing involve bitfield extract / insert, or some bithack to block or cancel carry propagation into the high half when incrementing the low half.  But does reduce cache/memory footprint by a factor of 2.  (Still only 1 chance in 4096 for a 31-bit number's counter bucket to be in a cache line that was hot in a 256kiB L2 cache, assuming uniform distribution, so that's not helpful, not even for 32MiB L3).  And 4-bit counters leave the worst-case hashmap size *much* larger.

Comment: @PeterCordes: BUt 4b numbers with ~4b possible values means the average count of each value is 1, so the hashmap will still _probably_ remain quite small, with a pathological case of 256m entries.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I think the point of the exercise is making sure that the code will definitely work in every possible corner case, given some arbitrary limits Java puts on things like the size of a single array.  I suppose we can assume an effectively unlimited JVM that doesn't run into address-space limits on the total size of all objects, since that isn't mentioned.  (Otherwise a 2GiB array in a 32-bit JVM might not leave room for anything else.)  But anyway, can we assume a 256m entry HashMap will fit?  2GiB / 256m only allow 8 bytes per entry, so maybe not. And that would be at 100% capacity.

Comment: @PeterCordes If the input could be arbitrairy numbers, no computer can store even a single number in all cases, let print the highest 100. Assuming non-negative 32 (31) bit integers is reasonable in my opinion, as the example input fits that description.

Comment: Sure, that's fair.  We do know that together all 4G numbers fit in a file that fits in some real-world filesystem, though.  And the fact that the number of numbers is 4G makes me thing maybe they're at least 32-bit, to make it possible for them to all be unique.  Definitely a useful answer for the case where this assumption is correct, and you did clearly state the assumption / condition under which this works, so I definitely upvoted.  In hindsight, I wouldn't have phrased my first comment that negatively.

Answer (score 17):

In pseudocode:

1. Perform an [external sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting)
2. Do a pass to collect the top 100 frequencies (not which values have them)
3. Do another pass to collect the values that have those frequencies

Assumption: There are clear winners - no ties (outside the top 100).

Time complexity: O(n log n) (approx) due to sort.
Space complexity: Available memory, again due to sort.

Steps 2 and 3 are both O(n) time and O(1) space.

---

If there are no ties (outside the top 100), steps 2 and 3 can be combined into one pass, which wouldn’t improve the time complexity, but would improve the run time slightly.

If there are ties that would make the quantity of winners large, you couldn’t discover that and take special action (e.g., throw error or discard all ties) without two passes. You could however find the smallest 100 values from the ties with one pass.

Comment: I learnt a new thing, [external sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting)

Comment: `3.` is not hard ("O(n)") than the original problem processing the output of `1.`

Answer (score 9):

> But it probably would throw an OutOfMemory exception for the data set of 4000000000 numbers. Moreover, since 4000000000 exceeds max length of Java array, let's say numbers are in a text file and they are not sorted.

That depends on the value distribution. If you have 4E9 numbers, but the numbers are integers 1-1000, then you will end up with  a map of 1000 entries. If the numbers are doubles or the value space is unrestricted, then you may have an issue.

As in [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64870685/how-can-i-get-the-most-frequent-100-numbers-out-of-4-000-000-000-numbers/64871678#64871678) - there's a bug

```
unsorted.put(number, unsorted.getOrDefault(number, 0) + 1);
```

I personally would use "AtomicLong" for value, it allows to increase the value without updating the HashMap entries.

> I assume multithreading or Map Reduce would be more appropriate for big data set?
> What would be the most efficient solution for this problem?

This is a typical map-reduce exercise example, so in theory you could use multi-threaded or M-R approach. Maybe it's the goal of your exercise and you suppose to implement the multithreaded map-reduce tasks regardless if it's the most efficient way or not.

In reality you should calculate if it is worth the effort. If you're reading the input serially (as it's in your code using the `Scanner`), then definitely not. If you can split the input files and read multiple parts in parallel, considering the I/O throughput, it may be the case.

Or maybe if the value space is too large to fit into memory and you will need to downscale the dataset, you may consider different approach.

Answer (score 6):

Since the data set is presumably too big for memory, I'd do a hexadecimal [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). So the data set would get split between 16 files in each pass with as many passes as needed to get to the largest integer.

The second part would be to combine the files into one large data set.

The third part would be to read the file number by number and count the occurrence of each number. Save the number and number of occurrences into a two-dimensional array (the list) which is sorted by size. If the next number from the file has more occurrences than the number in the list with the lowest occurrences then replace that number.

Answer (score 6):

One option is a type of binary search.  Consider a binary tree where each split corresponds to a bit in a 32-bit integer.  So conceptually we have a binary tree of depth 32.  At each node, we can compute the count of numbers in the set that start with the bit sequence for that node.  This count is an O(n) operation, so the total cost of finding our most common sequence is going to be O(n * f(n)) where the function depends on how many nodes we need to enumerate.

Let's start by considering a depth-first search.  This provides a reasonable upper bound to the stack size during enumeration.  A brute force search of all nodes is obviously terrible (in that case, you can ignore the tree concept entirely and just enumerate over all the integers), but we have two things that can prevent us from needing to search all nodes:

1. If we ever reach a branch where there are 0 numbers in the set starting with that bit sequence, we can prune that branch and stop enumerating.
2. Once we hit a terminal node, we know how many occurrences of that specific number there are.  We add this to our 'top 100' list, removing the lowest if necessary.  Once this list fills up, we can start pruning any branches whose total count is lower than the lowest of the 'top 100' counts.

I'm not sure what the average and worst-case performance for this would be.  It would tend to perform better for sets with fewer distinct numbers and probably performs worst for sets that approach uniformly distributed, since that implies more nodes will need to be searched.

A few observations:

1. There are at most N terminal nodes with non-zero counts, but since N > 2^32 in this specific case, that doesn't matter.
2. The total number of nodes for M leaf nodes (M = 2^32) is 2M-1.  This is still linear in M, so worst case running time is bounded above at O(N*M).
3. This will perform worse than just searching all integers for some cases, but only by a linear scalar factor.  Whether this performs better on average depends on the the expected data.  For uniformly random data sets, my intuitive guess is that you'd be able to prune enough branches once the top-100 list fills up that you would tend to require fewer than M counts, but that would need to evaluated empirically or proven.
4. As a practical matter, the fact that this algorithm just requires read-only access to the data set (it only ever performs a count of numbers starting with a certain bit pattern) means it is amenable to parallelization by storing the data across multiple arrays, counting the subsets in parallel, then adding the counts together.  This could be a pretty substantial speedup in a practical implementation that's harder to do with an approach that requires sorting.

---

A concrete example of how this might execute, for a simpler set of 3-bit numbers and only finding the single most frequent.  Let's say the set is '000, 001, 100, 001, 100, 010'.

1. Count all numbers that start with '0'.  This count is 4.
2. Go deeper, count all numbers that start with '00'.  This count is 3.
3. Count all numbers that are '000'.  This count is 1.  This is our new most frequent.
4. Count all numbers that are '001'.  This count is 2.  This is our new most frequent.
5. Take next deep branch and count all numbers that start with '01'.  This count is 1, which is less than our most frequent, so we can stop enumerating this branch.
6. Count all numbers that start with '1'.  This count is 1, which is less than our most frequent, so we can stop enumerating this branch.
7. We're out of branches, so we're done and '001' is the most frequent.

Comment: are you building a data structure as you read through the input file?  I don't follow what you are actually doing here.

Comment: @JDługosz, There is a data structure for the top-100 list, but I've ignored that for the purposes of this discussion (could be a priority queue.)  The binary tree in this case is conceptual, as we only have to visit a subset of the nodes and compute a count for each node we visit.  The depth-first enumeration process will involve a stack, most likely, but we never explicitly store a tree structure in memory.  The tree is just the abstraction we use to describe the enumeration process we're doing.

Comment: @JDługosz: If you rearrange the steps, this is functionally the equivalent of "count how many 0 values there are, then count how many 1 values there are, etc + if the count isn't in the current top 100, discard this value." -> O(n*value_range). The binary search bit gives it a slight optimization of skipping ranges of values that all have a counts small enough to not make the list, but I suspect the complexity makes it slower than the naive.

Comment: since N > 2^32 in this specific case, that doesn't matter." It's worth noting that N<2^32 here, but they're very close.

Comment: @MooingDuck, Ah, you're correct on the size of N, I was thinking of it in terms of the max value of a signed integer.  But, yeah, large enough that the tree is likely to be fairly full.  There isn't a lot of added complexity for the count (bitmasking while counting should be quite fast and I suspect can be optimized to run in a way that doesn't use branching), so it would be a matter of whether sufficient pruning can occur to make the added overhead worthwhile.  Whether that's the case depends on how the input data is distributed.

Comment: `not sure [about] average and worst-case performance` evaluate those 4E9-100 distinct numbers.

Answer (score 5):

#### Linux tools

That's simply done in a shell script on Linux/Mac:

```
sort inputfile | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 100
```

If the data is already sorted, you just use

```
uniq -c inputfile | sort -nr | head -n 100
```

#### File system

Another idea is to use the number as the filename and increase the file size for each hit

```
while read number;
do
  echo -n "." >> number
done <<< inputfile
```

File system constraints could cause trouble with that many files, so you can create a directory tree with the first digits and store the files there.

When finished, you traverse through the tree and remember the 100 highest seen values for file size.

#### Database

You can use the same approach with a database, so you don't need to actually store the GB of data there (works too), just the counters (needs less space).

#### Interview

An interesting question would be how you handle edge cases, so what should happen if the 100th, 101st, ... number have the same frequency. Are the integers only positive?

What kind of output do they need, just the numbers or also the frequencies? Just think it through like a real task at work and ask everything you need to know to solve it. It's more about how you think and analyze a problem.

Comment: warning though, sort and uniq is likely going to use over 36GB of RAM each, the combination of sort and uniq here is probably going to use over 90GB of ram

Comment: @Timur has tried it out, see his answer. Cannot comment on his answer yet, but would be interested if my "sort -nr" produces different results than his "sort -r".

Comment: On my mac this creates different results: `echo -e "1\n2\n12\n22" | sort -r`
22
2
12
1
`echo -e "1\n2\n12\n22" | sort -nr`
22
12
2
1

Answer (score 4):

I have noticed there is a bug in this line.

```
unsorted.put(number, unsorted.getOrDefault(number, 1) + 1);
```

You should make the default value as 0 as you are then adding 1 to it. If not when you only have 1 occurrence of a value, it is recorded as the frequency of 2.

```
unsorted.put(number, unsorted.getOrDefault(number, 0) + 1);
```

One downside that I see is the unnecessity of keeping all 4 billion frequencies when you are sorting.

You can use a `PriorityQueue` to hold only 100 values.

```
    Map<String, Integer> unsorted = new HashMap<>();

    PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> highestFrequentValues = new PriorityQueue<>(100,
            (o1, o2) -> o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue()));

    // O(n)
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"))) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String number = scanner.nextLine();
            unsorted.put(number, unsorted.getOrDefault(number, 0) + 1);
        }
    }

    // O(n)
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> stringIntegerEntry : unsorted.entrySet()) {
        if (highestFrequentValues.size() < 100) {
            highestFrequentValues.add(stringIntegerEntry);
        } else {
            Map.Entry<String, Integer> minFrequencyWithinHundredEntries = highestFrequentValues.poll();
            if (minFrequencyWithinHundredEntries.getValue() < stringIntegerEntry.getValue()) {
                highestFrequentValues.add(stringIntegerEntry);
            }
        }
    }

    // O(n)
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> frequentValue : highestFrequentValues) {
        System.out.println(frequentValue.getKey());
    }
```

Comment: The bug seems inconsequential, since all we care about is relative frequency. It adds 1 to all frequencies, so the ordering is the same.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I know that the question is about Java and algorithms and solving this problem otherwise is not the point, but I still think this solution must be posted for completeness.

Solution in `sh`:

```
 sort FILE | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 100
```

Explanation: `sort | uniq -c` lists only unique entries and counts the number of their occurrences in the input; `sort -nr` sorts the output numerically in reverse order (the lines with more occurrences on the top); `head -n 100` keeps 100 top lines only. A file with 4,000,000,000 numbers up to 999999999 (as per OP) will take about ~40GB, so fits well on a disk of a single machine, so it is technically possible to use this solution.

Pro: simple, has constant and limited memory usage. Cons: sub-optimal (because of `sort`), consumes lots of the temporary disk space for the operation, and overall there is no doubt that a solution specifically designed for this problem will have a much better performance. The question remains (in all seriousness): in a general case, will writing (and then debugging and executing) an optimized solution take more or less time than using a sub-optimal one (as above) but available immediately? I ran the solution on a sample file with 400,000,000 lines (10x smaller) and it took about 7 minutes on my computer.

---

P.S. On a side note, OP mentions that this question was asked during a programming interview. This is interesting because I think this a kind of a solution worth mentioning in this context before starting to code another program from scratch. When people say "experienced engineers are 10x faster...", I personally don't think that this is because experienced engineers code faster or produce optimized algorithms off the top of the head, but because they explore the alternatives that can save time. In the context of an interview it is an important skill to demonstrate among others.

Comment: How does [`sort`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) actually work? [Merge sort using temporary files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Use_with_tape_drives)? Or using all available physical RAM? Or using some fixed-size buffer?

Comment: How long did it take for 4,000,000,000 numbers? On what system (RAM size, CPU, operating system (incl. version), disk type (SSD/rotating rust, read/write speed, etc.))? What was the max. RAM usage for executable `sort` (or child processes)?

Comment: Yes, GNU implementation is a merge sort indeed: https://superuser.com/questions/234054/unix-sort-algorithm-implementation . In terms of RAM usage, yes, if the input data doesn't fit entirely in RAM, RAM is only used as a buffer. User may define a buffer size and, if not defined by the user, `sort` will try to calculate a default one based on the size of the input files. During the sort RAM usage won't exceed the buffer size. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514283/gnu-sort-default-buffer-size .

Comment: On Linux, with an 8-core i7 CPU, an SSD disk, and with 5G of RAM for a buffer, following are the results with a 4,000,000,000-lines file (38GB): `time sort -S 5G nums.txt | uniq -c | sort -r | head -n 100` --> `1:18:32.71 total`. The process also used additional ~43GB of temporary disk space (38GB + 5GB while merging first temporary files).

Comment: @Timur 38GB? where those 32bit numbers or 64bit numbers? and how were they stored? i generated 4,000,000,000 64bit-numbers stored as ascii separated by newlines using [this script](https://gist.github.com/divinity76/7c25429fcdb64253ba0512ff33e9360e), and the file came out at 75 GB (or 79518110183 bytes to be exact)

Comment: @handhenrik, yes, certainly the file size depends on the values. In the test I performed the numbers where in range [0, 999999999], as per OP example.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that 4 trillion was chosen to be sure the problem is too large to fit in memory on current desktop machines.  So rent a large VM from Amazon or Microsoft for the purpose?  That's an answer most people don't think of yet but is valid for real-world solutions.

The way I'd approach it is start by *binning*.  The range of numbers is presumably all 32-bit unsigned integers (or whatever they said).  How large of an array does fit in RAM?  divide the range into that many equal bins and pass through the data once.  Look over the distribution:  Is it fairly uniform, or spikey, or a curve of some kind?  If the first/last range of bins are zeros then it gives you the true range of input values, and you can adjust the program to just bin over that range and repeat, to get better accuracy.

<strike>Then depending on the distribution, decide how to proceed.  In general, only the top 100 bins can possibly contain the top 100 values, so you can reconfigure with those ranges and the largest bins you can handle within that excerpted range.  If the distribution is too uniform, you might get many many bins with all the same count, so drop the smaller bins even though you have many more than 100 bins remaining -- you still cut it down *some*.</strike>

Worst case is that all the bins come out the same and you can't cut it down this way!  Someone prepared some pathological data assuming this kind of approach.  So re-arrange the way you do the binning.  Rather than simply chopping into contiguous ranges of equal size,  us a 1:1 mapping to shuffle them.  However, for large bins, this might preserve the property of being fairly uniform, so you don't want a conventional "good" hashing function.

#### Another approach

If binning works, and rapidly cuts down the problem, it's easy.  But the data could be such that it's actually very difficult.  So what's a way that always works, regardless of the data?  Well, I can assume that the result exists: some 100 values will have more occurrences.

Instead of bins, pick n specific values (however many you can fit in memory).  Either choose random numbers, or use the first N distinct values from your input.  Count those, and copy the others to another file.  That is, the values you don't have room to count get copied to a (smaller the original) file.

Now you'll at least have a useful pivot value:  the exact cardinality of the 100 distinct top values that you did count exactly.  Well, the ones you picked might still end up being all the same count!  So you only have 1 distinct cardinality worst case.  You know that this is not a "top" value since there are far more an 100 of them.

Run again on your new (smaller) file, and discard counts that are smaller than the top 100 you already know.  Repeat.

This reminds me of something that I might have read in Knuth's [TAOCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming), but scaled up for modern machine sizes.

Comment: *In general, only the top 100 bins can possibly contain the top 100 values,* - can you justify this?  I don't think it is true.

Comment: Agreed. The top 100 bins don't even necessarily contain the top 1 value.

Comment: 4,000,000,000 is 4 billion, not trillion.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Yes, a [trillion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trillion) is either 1E12 or 1E18, depending on the use of [short scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales) and [long scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales). A [billion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion) is either  1E9 or 1E12 (short scale and long scale, respectively)

Comment: There isn't any need for strikeout (that is what the revision history is for) - the answer should be as if it was written right now.

Answer (score 3):

I would just drop all the numbers in a database ([SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) would be my first choice) with a table like

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
number INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
counter INTEGER
)
```

Then for every number received, just do a

```
INSERT INTO tbl (number,counter) VALUES (:number,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter=counter+1;
```

or with SQLite syntax

```
INSERT INTO tbl (number,counter) VALUES (:number,1) ON CONFLICT(number) DO UPDATE SET counter=counter+1;
```

Then when all the numbers are accounted for,

```
SELECT number, counter FROM tbl ORDER BY counter DESC LIMIT 100
```

... then I would end up with the 100 most common numbers, and how often they occurred. This scheme will only break when you run out of disk space... (or when you reach ~[20000000000000 (20 trillion) unique digits](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) at some ~281 terabytes of disk space... )

Answer (score 1):

1. Divide your numbers into two buckets
2. Find top 100 in each bucket
3. Merge those top 100 lists.

To divide, do [median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) (which can be modified to make medians of the top/bottom as well).

Each bucket has a distinct range of numbers in it.  The initial median split makes 2 buckets, each with half (about) as many elements as the entire list in it.

To find the top 100, first know if the bucket is narrow (similar minimum and maximum) O(1) or small (few numbers in it) (O(n) time O(n*bucket count) memory).  If either is true, a simple counting pass (possibly doing more than 1 bucket at once) solves it (you will have to do it more than once probably, as you have memory limits).

If neither is true, recurse and divide that bucket into two.

There are going to be fiddly bits with how you recurse without wasting too much time.

But the idea is that each bucket exponentially gets narrower or smaller.  Narrow buckets have a minimum and maximum that is close, and small buckets have few elements.

You merge buckets so that you have enough storage to count the elements in the bucket (either width based, or volume based).  Then you do a pass that counts that bucket and finds the top 100, and repeat.  Each time you merge the top 100 from the scan into the previous top 100.

In-place, no sorting of the entire list needed, and devolves to simpler and more optimal strategies when the initial "bucket" is narrow or small.

Comment: Re *"In-place"*: Do you mean *"[In case](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_case#Conjunction)"*?

Comment: Nice idea, but won't yield the correct answer. You might miss a high frequency number if it is spread across many initial buckets.

Comment: @KrisVanBael The buckets are value based.  Not offset based.  So like "1 to 100" "101 to 1072", etc.  Counting how many elements are in each bucket (the volume) requires walking the entire list.  Finding the "width" of the bucket is max-min+1.  That is why you find the median of the numbers in the list to form the first two buckets.

Comment: What does "In-place" refer to?

Comment: @peter not making a copy of the elements (in general; some values are copied)

Comment: How will you calculate the median? Doesn't that require a sort?

Comment: @KrisVanBael The median of median algorithm doesn't require a sort -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians .  And picking K elements at random and taking their median generates a really, really high quality approximation for the median much cheaper than that.  In general, kth element is O(n) not O(n lg n).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the point of the challenge is to process this large amount of data without consuming too much memory, and avoid parsing the input too many times.

Here's an algorithm that would require two not too large arrays. Don't know about java, but I am confident that this can be made to run *very* fast in C:

Create a **Count** array of size 2^n to count the number of input numbers based on their n most significant bits. That will require a first scan over the input data but is really straightforward to do. I would first try with n=20 (about one million buckets).

Obviously, we won't process the data one bucket at a time, as that would require reading the input a million times, instead we choose our optimal batch size B and allocate a **Batch** array of size B. B could be like 40M, so that we aim at reading the input about 100 times. (It all depends on available memory).

Then we iterate over the count array to group the first range of buckets so that the sum is close to, but doesn't exceed B.

For each such range, we parse the input data, look for numbers in range and copy those numbers to the batch array. Since we already know the size of each bucket, we can immediately copy them grouped per bucket, so that we only have to sort them bucket by bucket (you can repurpose the count array to store the indices for where to write the next entry). Next we count the identical items in the sorted batch array and keep track of the top 100 so far.

Proceed the next range of buckets for which the sum of counts is under size B, etc...

**Optimizations:**

- Once we start having a decent top 100, you can skip entire buckets whose size is below our 100th entry. For this we can use a special value (such as -1) in the count array, to indicate there is not index. Depending on the data, this can drastically reduce the number of passes required.
- When counting identical items in the sorted Batch, we can make jumps of the size of your 100th entry (and then take a few steps backwards. I can share pseudo-code if needed)

**Potential issues with this approach:**
The input numbers could be concentrated in a small range, then you might get one or more single buckets that are larger than B. Possible solutions:

1. You could try another selection of n bits instead (eg. the n least significant bits). Note that that still won't help if the same numbers appears a billion times.
2. If the input is 32bit integers, then the range of possible values is limited, and there can only be a few thousand different numbers in each bucket. So if one bucket is really large, then we can process that bucket differently: Just keep a counter for each unique value in that range. We can repurpose the Batch array for that.